# IIS 7 How to map a client certificate with a user account in a database?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7, certificate

Here it is said http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/04/27/configuring-many-to-one-client-certificate-mappings-for-iis-7-7-5.aspx

Many-to-one Client certificate mapping is used by the Internet Information Services (IIS) to associate an end user to a **windows account** when the client certificate is used for the user authentication.

What if I don't want to map with a windows account but with an account in custom database or in membership ?

How to do it in asp.net (sample code somewhere ?)

hmm: nobody knows ? Will have to give bounty soon :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US DOD uses this for CAC.  Essentially, you just store some part of the certificate (say the SUBJECT) and then compare against this for authentication.

In ASP.Net, you access the Client Cert thusly:

> Request.ClientCertificate.Subject

Many certificate subjects will have a unique id within and so the certificate id is used to cover for changes in the individuals name.